# catalina.sh system variable from docker-compose environments

Tags: java, docker, tomcat, environment-variables, catalina

I have the following problem.
I want to set some JAVA_OPTS from environment variables described into the docker-compose.yml file in order to use them into my **context.xml** of **tomcat**

example:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: myapp
    container_name: myapp
    environment:
      - DBURL=192.168.7.17
      - DBPORT=3306
      - DBUSERNAME=test
      - DBPASSWORD=test
```

**context.xml**

```
<Resource
        auth="Container"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"

        initialSize="0"
        maxActive="10"
        maxIdle="5"
        maxWait="5000"
        minIdle="0"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"

        testOnBorrow="true"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        testOnReturn="false"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM dual"
        validationInterval="30000"
        removeAbandoned="true"
        removeAbandonedTimeout="10"

        name="jdbc/dbschema"
        username="${db_username}"
        password="${db_password}"
        url="jdbc:mysql://${db_url}:${db_port}/dbschema?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8"
    />
```

Following some tomcat guides, I have found that System variables have to be set into the **catalina.sh** script or into **setenv.sh** script.

So, my catalina.sh file contains this line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddb_url=$DBURL -Ddb_port=$DBPORT -Ddb_username=$DBUSERNAME -Ddb_password=$DBPASSWORD"
```

But, executing `ps aux | grep java` from the container, I have:

```
root        26  6.5 13.8 5770472 1120204 ?     Sl   09:04   1:38 /usr/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Ddb_url= -Ddb_port= -Ddb_username= -Ddb_password= -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

The **Dockerfile** of app is:

```
FROM bp91/ubuntu16.04-tomcat7-java8

COPY webapps /tmp/webapps/

ADD tomcat/bin /opt/tomcat/bin/

RUN chmod 775 /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

RUN chown root:root /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

RUN cp -r /tmp/webapps/* /opt/tomcat/webapps/

EXPOSE 8282

CMD service tomcat start && touch /opt/tomcat/logs/myapp.log && tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/myapp.log
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried this:

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  myapp:
    build:
      context: myapp
      args:
            db_url: 192.168.7.17
            db_port: 3306
            db_username: eudata
            db_password: eudata
    container_name: myapp
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM bp91/ubuntu16.04-tomcat7-java8

COPY webapps /tmp/webapps/

ADD tomcat/bin /opt/tomcat/bin/

RUN chmod 775 /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

RUN chown root:root /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

RUN cp -r /tmp/webapps/* /opt/tomcat/webapps/

ARG db_url
ARG db_port
ARG db_username
ARG db_password

ENV db_url ${db_url}
ENV db_port ${db_port}
ENV db_username ${db_username}
ENV db_password ${db_password}

EXPOSE 8282

CMD service tomcat start && touch /opt/tomcat/logs/myapp.log && tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/myapp.log
```

I've added the following setenv.sh file into tomcat/bin folder:

```
echo "I'm in setenv.sh"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddb_url=$db_url -Ddb_port=$db_port -Ddb_username=$db_username -Ddb_password=$db_password"

export JAVA_OPTS
```

But nothing. If I try to print environment variables into setenv.sh like this:

```
echo "Environment variables"

env

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddb_url=$db_url -Ddb_port=$db_port -Ddb_username=$db_username -Ddb_password=$db_password"

export JAVA_OPTS
```

I can't see no one setted variables (db_url, db_port, db_username or db_password).

**UPDATE 3**

I've followed this way:

I've a docker-compse.yml like this:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: myapp
    container_name: myapp
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Djdbc.url=192.168.7.17 -Djdbc.port=3306 -Djdbc.username=test -Djdbc.password=test
```

My **server.xml**:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
   <Resource
      auth="Container"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      global="jdbc/myapp"

      initialSize="0"
      maxActive="10"
      maxIdle="5"
      maxWait="5000"
      minIdle="0"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"

      testOnBorrow="true"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM dual"
      validationInterval="30000"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="10"

      name="jdbc/myapp"
      username="${jdbc.username}"
      password="${jdbc.password}"
      url="jdbc:mysql://${jdbc.url}:${jdbc.port}/interaction_server?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8"
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

The **context.xml**:

```
<Context>
    <ResourceLink
        name="jdbc/myapp"
        global="jdbc/myapp"

        auth="Container"

        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    />
</Context>
```

But I've the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myAppServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal connection port value '${jdbc.port}'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)....
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: You could enter the container's bash. And check if the environments variables are set correctly by executing `env` or `echo $DBUSERNAME`

Comment: Yes, `echo $DBUSERNAME` prints `test`

Comment: My guess would be that he is unable to replace any of the environment variables including $JAVA_OPTS. Have you already tried doing the same but using the setenv.sh file?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @DavidMaes see **Update 2** on the edit. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Working in this way:

**docker-compose.yml**:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: myapp
    container_name: myapp
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS= -Ddb.url=192.168.7.17 -Ddb.port=3306 -Ddb.username=test -Ddb.password=test
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM bp91/ubuntu16.04-tomcat7-java8

COPY webapps /tmp/webapps/

ADD tomcat/bin /opt/tomcat/bin/

RUN chmod 775 /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

RUN chown root:root /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh

RUN cp -r /tmp/webapps/* /opt/tomcat/webapps/

ENV JAVA_OPTS ""

EXPOSE 8282

CMD sh /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh $JAVA_OPTS && touch /opt/tomcat/logs/myapp.log && tail -f /opt/tomcat/logs/myapp.log
```

**server.xml**:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
   <Resource
      auth="Container"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      global="jdbc/myapp"

      initialSize="0"
      maxActive="10"
      maxIdle="5"
      maxWait="5000"
      minIdle="0"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"

      testOnBorrow="true"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM dual"
      validationInterval="30000"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="10"

      name="jdbc/myapp"
      username="${db.username}"
      password="${db.password}"
      url="jdbc:mysql://${db.url}:${db.port}/myapp?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8"
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

Comment: Working for me! Thanks